# Why is Tensorflow image processing is slow

Tags: python, image, performance, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I am making some tfrecord files with images, to use with the HUB inceptionV3 module.
When creating I use for TF:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as inputFileObj:
        image = sess.run(tf.image.decode_image(inputFileObj.read()))
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = sess.run(tf.image.resize_images(image, [299, 299]))
```

This takes around 40 seconds for the first 100 images, 110 seconds for the next 100, and it keeps growing in time and memory use

When using PIL I get 1.5 seconds per 100 images for the same code.
code with PIL

```
img = pil_image.open(filePath)
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    img = img.convert('RGB')
img = img.resize([299,299], pil_image.BICUBIC)
img = np.asarray(img)
scale = 1. / np.iinfo(img.dtype).max
img = img.astype(np.float32)*scale
```

I am tempted to say that Tensorflow has memory leaks of some sort ?

using tensorflow 1.8.0
The complete cycle is open file and write into a TFRecord

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(outputFile)
totalDocs = 0
lastTime = time.time()
for picFile, label in inputData:
    totalDocs += 1
    if totalDocs%100 == 0:
        print "done %d in %f sec" % (totalDocs, time.time() - lastTime)
        lastTime = time.time()
    image = open_resize_image(picFile)
    feature = {'label': _bytes_feature(label),
               'image':_bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image.tostring()))}
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Comment: "for the first 100 images", but, if I understand well, your code only reads one image at a time. So, how can we reproduce your problem?!

Comment: I am doing it in a loop for 3K images and writting into a TFrecord
updated the question to add the iteration code.
Assume the open_resize_image() is the code above for PIL and TF

Comment: I would need a reproducible example to try helping you. There are undefined functions in your code snippets, which make it pretty hard to answer a performance question.

Comment: All code is there. Only missing the imports of tf and pillow .
On the last code the `open_resize_image` is one of two implementations seen above.